# Python - convert a list in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I got a list of values and i would like to convert it in an array in order to extract easily columns, but i m embarassed with " which doesn t allow to use : " x = np.array(a, dtype=float)"

```
['"442116.503118","442116.251106"',
     '"442141.502863","442141.247462"',
    ...
```

The message obtained is :
"could not convert string to float: "442116.503118","442116.251106""

Comment: You have a list of strings, you need to convert these to float first before constructing an array of floats

Comment: You have 2 levels of quoting: `'"...","..."'`.  `np.array()` can only handle one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just wrong... This does the trick for me though:

```
import numpy as np

wtf = ['"442116.503118","442116.251106"',
     '"442141.502863","442141.247462"']

to_list = []

for nest1 in wtf:
    nest2 = nest1.split(',')
    for each in nest2:
        to_list.append(float(each.strip('"')))

to_array = np.asarray(to_list)
```

Not exactly elegant. You need to deal with each level of nesting in your input data. I'd recommend you reconsider the way you're formatting the data you're inputting.

Comment: thanks for your help ;) it works! but you have to change "each" by "val"

Comment: sorry there is a mistake, the values are the same in each columns

Comment: Sorry, must have copied over the code wrong. I've edited my answer and it should now be correct.

I don't understand what you mean by columns? Is it that 442116.503118 and 42141.502863 should be in 1 column and the rest of the values in another? If so, you can do `to_array.reshape(-1,2)` to get them that way. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Answering based on the VERY limited information given, but if that is your list it looks like a list of nested strings, not floats. Try

`x = np.array([float(i.replace("\"","")) for i in a], dtype=float)"`

Comment: But it's a list of nested strings, the first string is two doublequoted numbers all in single quotes `'"442116.503118","442116.251106"'`

Comment: doesnt work i got : "could not convert string to float: "442116.503118","442116.251106"
"

Comment: ok well read the error and figure out what is going on, geez. I've edited my answer.